# Deploying smart contracts on Polygon mainnet using Hardhat-Deploy

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have been working on Polygon Mumbai testnet for several months now. It is time to deploy to mainnet and I have setup my deployment with hardhat-deploy plugin. I set up the dependencies and all the parameters for all my smart contracts. However, I have encountered some issues. When I run deploy, first few contracts gets deployed as expected then some of the contracts get stuck and when I run the command again. It give me the error "replacement transaction underpriced" then run the deploy command multiple times and get the same error then It asks me to either increase the gas price or try again but It won't work whatever options I select. I set the gas price inside the script for the contract that gets stuck and it works.

I don't want to set this gas price inside scripts because correct me if I am wrong, I need to set it based on gas price at the time of deployment on mainnet, so I don't want to set it manually for all the contracts or put a very high gas price for all of them.

Also, I am doing some initialization, token transfers inside the deployment scripts. For example:

1. deploy Contract A
2. transfer erc20 token from owner to Contract A
3. call initialize() function of Contract A

Is it a good practice or should I just deploy the scripts then run a seperate script to do all these initalizations etc.

I would appreciate if you could lead me in the right direction here to make a smooth deployment on mainnet and make any additional comments on deployment process on mainnet that I need to consider.